# Encoding and Decoding API Access token with keys

Tags: api, python-3.x, security, cryptography, access-token

I am planning to secure my rest API in django with a ACCESS_TOKEN.
When ever user is logged in using their username and password, once they are authenticated, I generate a ACCESS_TOKEN and passed to frontend be it Website or Native application. and then later used that ACCESS_TOKEN for further communication.
I am generating this token based on some user data and then encrypting this with public key. Later when application send this for in any request, I decrypt the ACCESS_TOKEN with private key and extract user data data and process the request. This is something similar to session where session data is in encrypted form in ACCESS_TOKEN and only private key and decrypt the ACCESS_TOKEN. This is what I am planning to do.
Please suggest me for following questions:-
1. Is is the best way to secure my REST API? I want to use my API in same way from Web-application(AJAX calling) and NATIVE application(Android/IOS etc) ?
2. What is the best way to expire the token? Do I need to keep track of access token at my end in order to expire them?

Also I do want to use the Oauth in my API.

Comment: Why does the token need to contain any data at all?  If its a unique value it can be reconciled on the server via a database to whatever information you like, this way no data crosses from client to server at all.

Comment: I do want the token to behave more like JWT but do not want my data to be decode-able from any way except private key

Answer (score 0):

Most people I see use JWT's that are signed but not encrypted so they store non-PI data like user_id or session_id. I guess you could encrypt it if needing to store personal information but I don't see any other reason. Assuming you are using HTTPS, then only the end client would have access to the information. Sounds like asking for trouble if the secret gets leaked so you would want a really good key rotation scheme since you may not even know its leaked until too late.

Many people using JWTs do so because they don't want a centralized auth server, thus the token is short lived like a few hours or days. If you need really tight control on expiring tokens, you can take a blacklist approach where a blacklist of JTI's (JWT Ids) are stored in a K/V to be checked against. https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/restful-apis/Authorization-on-RESTful-APIs/